# Accessing PowerDesigner Repository Models via COM

Tags: java, vba, com, sybase, powerdesigner

I have been trying to get live models directly from the PowerDesigner repository using the COM API without success.  Here's what I've been trying in VBA:

```
Set pd = CreateObject("PowerDesigner.Application")
Set conn = pd.RepositoryConnection
conn.Open "", "", "ShhMahPW"

Set model = conn.FindChildByPath("Program/Project/Logical Models/MahLOM", PdOOM_Classes.cls_Model)

MsgBox model.ShortDescription 'This fails because model is null!
```

Similarly, I've been trying the same thing in Eclipse with the Java COM bridge:

```
Application pd = this.getApplicationHook();

//Make live connection to proxy repository
RepositoryConnection conn = new RepositoryConnection( pd.GetRepositoryConnection() );
conn.Open( "", "", ConnectionParams.PASSWORD );


BaseObject model = conn.FindChildByPath( "Program/Project/Logical Models/MahLOM", 
                   PdOOM_Classes.cls_Model );

//Null model, COMException: "Action can not be performed. result = -2147467259"
System.out.println( model.GetShortDescription() )
```

Can someone please suggest a good way of diving into the repository?  I have been able to confirm that I have a connection to the repo and then list the children at that top level.  I am struggling to dig into folders beyond the root level.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew that the model I was looking to pull down from the repo already existed in my local workspace.  Really this was a refresh of the local workspaces models.  To perform this, the method `UpdateFromRepository()` can be used!

So what I can do then is get a handle to the local PowerDesigner model and then call for an update before retrieving children.  Note the casting from `BaseObject` to `BaseModel` for the sake of the refresh...

```
private BaseObject getModel(){

    Application pd = this.getApplicationHook();

    model = pd.OpenModel(this.basePath + this.modelName);
    System.out.println( "Retrieving model updates from repository...  ");

    RepositoryConnection conn = new RepositoryConnection( pd.GetRepositoryConnection() );
    conn.Open( "", "", ConnectionParams.PASSWORD);

    boolean success = new BaseModel(model).UpdateFromRepository();

    if( success )
        System.out.println( "Update successful!" );
    else
        System.out.println( "Update failed. Check PowerDesigner settings." );

    return this.model;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that the search `ChildKind` should be `Cls_RepositoryModel`, instead of `PdOOM_Class.cls_Model`.

```
   option explicit
   ' assuming we're already connected
   if RepositoryConnection.Connected then
      Descent RepositoryConnection,""
   end if
   dim c
   set c = RepositoryConnection.FindChildByPath("Folder_7/ConceptualDataModel_1", Cls_RepositoryModel)
   if not c is nothing then
      output "*** found object " & c.classname
   end if

sub Descent(obj,ofs)
   output ofs & obj.name & " - " & obj.ObjectType & " - " & obj.ClassName
   if obj.ObjectType = "RepositoryModel" then exit sub
   if obj.PermanentID = 3 then exit sub ' to save time, don't enter Library
   if not obj.HasCollection("ChildObjects") then exit sub
   dim c
   for each c in obj.ChildObjects
      Descent c,ofs & "   "
   next
end sub
```